# How to Dynamically cast the type of an 'Object' in apex at runtime

Tags: apex, sobject, dynamic-apex, type, casting

Let's say we have a Map<String,Object> we got from an lwc, and we need to create records for any given SObject that can change based on some custom metadata type records.

I have the following snippet but always get an error like invalid runtime conversion from type String to Schema.DisplayType

```
SObject record = (SObject) Type.forName(objectName)
     .newInstance();
 String fieldType = String.valueOf(record.getDescribe().fields
    .getMap()
    .get(fieldName)
    .getDescribe()
    .getType());
    Type displayType = Type.forName(fieldType);
     record.put(
        objectField, //name of the field
         (displayType) mapStringObjectWithMyValuesFromLWC.get(objectField)
     );
```

I may be missing a better approach. All help and input is appreciated :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `getType` method you are calling directly returns a `DisplayType` value rather than a `String` so change your code to:

```
DisplayType displayType = record.getDescribe().fields
    .getMap()
    .get(fieldName)
    .getDescribe()
    .getType();
```

See the [DescribeFieldResult documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm#apex_Schema_DescribeFieldResult_getType) for more detail.

**PS**

In response to the first comment, in your approach, you are running `Type.forName` on one of the `enum` values e.g. `DisplayType.Picklist` not the `enum` type `DisplayType`. So it's not going to work even if Apex treated `enum` as a special kind of `class`.

Also note that trying to cast a field value to a `DisplayType` won't work. For types other than strings you will likely need to write your own type conversion code based on the `DisplayType` or likely better based on the `SOAPType` that is also available from a describe call.

Given this complexity do consider if your overall approach here is appropriate.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion; I saw that I did not post the correct example of what I'm trying to do; yes, the last getType returns a Schema.DisplayType, but I was trying to get the string value and pass it down to the forName method of the Type class. This is constantly breaking on the type casting.

Comment: @SouthJoe I've added a **PS** to my original answer that I hope helps.